# Is it possible to install nvidia 310 drivers version on ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: drivers, 10.04, nvidia

I have just installed ubuntu 10.04 and want to install lastest nvidia drivers on it too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you meant 12.04 but either way, you should be able to install the drivers using `apt` as follows:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Comment: Latest driver for 10.04 from x-swat is 304.64